# Logging Stored Procedure Parameter Values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter, logging

I've worked in an SQL Server environment before where logging was made part of our stored procedures to capture execution start/end, parameter values and error messages which I found very useful and is something I'm looking to introduce in a new environment.

The tables used for this logging looked like something below, parameters were captured using `INSERT` statements into a table with the with values being implicitly cast to `NVARCHAR`.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Execution
(
    Id                  INT IDENTITY(1,1)           NOT NULL
,   SchemaName          NVARCHAR(128)               NOT NULL
,   ProcedureName       NVARCHAR(128)               NOT NULL
,   ExecutionStart      DATETIME                    NOT NULL
,   ExecutionEnd        DATETIME                    NULL
,   ExecutionFailed     BIT                         NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.ExecutionError
(
    Id                  INT IDENTITY(1,1)           NOT NULL
,   ExecutionId         INT                         NOT NULL
,   CustomErrorMessage  NVARCHAR(8000)              NULL
,   SqlErrorMessage     NVARCHAR(8000)              NULL
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.ExecutionParameter
(
    Id                  INT IDENTITY(1,1)           NOT NULL
,   ExecutionId         INT                         NOT NULL
,   ParameterName       NVARCHAR(128)               NOT NULL
,   ParameterValue      NVARCHAR(MAX)               NULL
)
```

I've been reconsidering the `ExecutionParameter` table with the possibility of using an `SQL_VARIANT` data type so I could get the base data type if ever needed for analysis and reporting purposes without having to guess based on the name/value.

However this wouldn't work for parameters that have a data type of `NVARCHAR(MAX)` or `VARCHAR(MAX)` and would therefore need to still have the `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column there which would be `NULL` the majority of the time.

The use of `SQL_VARIANT` is tempting but I feel the original table structure works fine and can't really be made any better without making the process more complicated.

Is this something you have done previously, if so how did you implement it? Can you see room for improvement in the above schema without making it overly complicated?

Perhaps an additional table with details of the stored procedure and their parameters which can be referenced? Though I feel this would be difficult to maintain and become confusing as stored procedures are modified over time.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you expect parameter inputs longer than 8000 bytes? If yes and you need failure logging for them, is it perhaps valuable to store a log for those data types on a separate table? For myself, in ExecutionParameter, I'd probably want to include the parameter data type as well ( to be able to quickly identify the Int value 2 vs the string value "2" for example ). Given that, would xml or json not be a more extensible storage method for this data? And if you're going that direction, then why not just store all the parameter information you want on dbo.ExecutionError?

Comment: Yes some will be, stored procedures are used for SSRS reports and multi-valued parameters can exceed 8000 characters. Storing parameter information on all executions, not just errors, is useful to get a better picture on slow running procedures and how people are using them etc. XML could be an option, I'd be interested to see an example.

Comment: Have you considered adding a `ParameterDataTypeName` column to `dbo.ExecutionParameter`?  I would ditch the Id column from that table and use a composite key of `ExecutionID` and `ParameterName` as well as use a primary key on `dbo.ExecutionError` of `ExecutionID` and ID. Store the parameter value as a formatted string for non-character types.

Comment: For ExecutionParameter then, can I suggested simply trimming with substring( @Param, 1, 8000 ) for the ability to query quickly from there. Additionally, you can store the full parameter value along with the name ( and any other elements ) as xml in line with ExecutionError ( sort of how ReportServer does it natively )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we did this type of thing at a company I worked at a few years ago. Even though we did it only for error logging, it was the same general concept. You just need to write the SELECT statement that includes all of the input parameters, use `FOR XML`, and store that in a variable that can be inserted into your `Execution` table in a new field: `Parameters XML NULL`. And then you can scrap the `ExecutionParameter` table.

Try the following as it shows three ways of generating the XML: Attribute-based, Element-based, and Element-based including NULL elements. The default behavior of `FOR XML` is to indicate `NULL` values by not including the attribute or element. But if you are doing Element-based XML and want the parameters to show even if they are `NULL`, then you need to specify `XSINIL` in the `FOR XML` clause. The ability to include an indicator for `NULL` is not available in Attribute-based XML.

Please note that there is not a huge difference between Attributed-based XML and the default Element-based XML (default = does not include `NULL` items) in terms of storage size (as shown in the example below). When viewing the XML it does appear that there is a lot more "bloat" with Element-based, and that would be the case if storing the data in an `NVARCHAR` field or text file. But the `XML` datatype uses an optimized method of storing the data internally, in a way that cannot be seen, but is clearly indicated in the resulting `DATALENGTH` output.

There is, however, a slight increase in size when using the `XSINIL` option for Element-based XML and it needs to keep track of `NULL` elements which are excluded from the other two types. The increase in size is due to a one-time hit for declaring the `xsi` namespace in the root element, and then a per-`NULL` element hit.

```sql
DECLARE @Param1 INT = 5,
        @Param2 DATETIME = NULL,
        @Param3 NVARCHAR(50) = N'Test < some & XML chars "',
        @Param4 DATETIME = '2016-04-09';

DECLARE @Parameters XML;

SELECT @Parameters = (
   SELECT @Param1 AS [Param1],
          @Param2 AS [Param2],
          @Param3 AS [Param3],
          @Param4 AS [Param4]
   FOR XML RAW(N'Params') -- Attribute-based XML (NULL attributes are missing)
);

SELECT @Parameters, DATALENGTH(@Parameters); -- 183

SELECT @Parameters = (
   SELECT @Param1 AS [Param1],
          @Param2 AS [Param2],
          @Param3 AS [Param3],
          @Param4 AS [Param4]
   FOR XML RAW(N'Params'), ELEMENTS -- Element-based XML (NULL elements are missing)
);

SELECT @Parameters, DATALENGTH(@Parameters); -- 185

SELECT @Parameters = (
   SELECT @Param1 AS [Param1],
          @Param2 AS [Param2],
          @Param3 AS [Param3],
          @Param4 AS [Param4]
   FOR XML PATH(N'Params'), ELEMENTS XSINIL -- Element-based XML (NULL elements included)
);

SELECT @Parameters, DATALENGTH(@Parameters); -- 434
```

Returned XML values:

```xml
<!-- Attribute-based -->
<Params Param1="5" Param3="Test &lt; some &amp; XML chars &quot;"
 Param4="2016-04-09T00:00:00" />


<!-- Element-based -->
<Params>
  <Param1>5</Param1>
  <Param3>Test &lt; some &amp; XML chars "</Param3>
  <Param4>2016-04-09T00:00:00</Param4>
</Params>


<!-- Element-based including NULL elements -->
<Params xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Param1>5</Param1>
  <Param2 xsi:nil="true" />
  <Param3>Test &lt; some &amp; XML chars "</Param3>
  <Param4>2016-04-09T00:00:00</Param4>
</Params>
```

---

Additional notes:

- For `SchemaName` and `ProcedureName` columns, I would use `sysname` as the datatype since that is how it is defined in the system tables. And be sure to use lower-case for `sysname` as it is an alias that lives in `master` and servers with a default collation that is binary or case-sensitive won't be able to find that alias if it is not all lower-case. Your current server might be case-insensitive, but it is still a good habit to get into when using `sysname`.
- For the `ExecutionError` table, be sure to include `INT` columns to capture: `ERROR_LINE()`, `ERROR_NUMBER()`, `ERROR_STATE()`, and `ERROR_SEVERITY()`.
- No, you don't want to use `SQL_VARIANT` as that prevents you from storing the LOB types: `VARCHAR(MAX)`, `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, `VARBINARY(MAX)`, and `XML`.
- No, you can't use `NVARCHAR(8000)` because `NVARCHAR` has a top size of 4000, unless you use `MAX`.

Comment: I think Element based allowing for NULLs would be the most suitable option as it will allow the data type to be stored as an attribute

Comment: That is great! I just simplified a bit when using single choice to
`DECLARE @Parameters XML = ( ..`